# Higher Variance due to Overfitting.

Tags: statistics, self-learning, regression, regression-analysis

This is a homework question.

Consider the following two regression models
$$\mathbf y=\mathbf X_1\mathbf {\beta_1} + \mathbf {\varepsilon}$$
$$\mathbf y=\mathbf X_1\mathbf {\beta_1} + \mathbf X_2\mathbf {\beta_2} + \mathbf {\varepsilon}$$

Where $\operatorname{Disp} (\mathbf {\varepsilon}) =\sigma^2\mathbf I$

Now, if the first model is correct, show that for any vector $\mathbf u$ one has

$$\operatorname{Var} \left( \mathbf {u'}\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(2)}\right) \ge \operatorname{Var} \left( \mathbf {u'}\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(1)}\right)$$

Where $\hat{\mathbf \beta_1}^{(1)}$ and $\hat {\mathbf \beta_1}^{(2)}$ are the Least-Square estimators of $\mathbf \beta_1$ from the first and second models respectively.

My attempt: The Least-Square (LS) estimators of $\mathbf \beta_1$ obtained from the first and second models are
$$\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(1)}=\mathbf {(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'y}$$
$$\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(2)}=\mathbf {(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'}( \mathbf y - \mathbf {X_2\hat {\beta_2}^{(2)}})$$
Now since $\mathbf {\hat \beta_2^{(2)}}$ is the LS estimator of $\mathbf \beta_2$, it is a linear function of $\mathbf y$. So we may write $\mathbf {X_2\hat \beta_2^{(2)}}= \mathbf {Sy}$. Hence

$\operatorname{Var} \left( \mathbf {u'}\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(2)}\right) - \operatorname{Var} \left( \mathbf {u'}\hat {\mathbf {\beta_1}}^{(1)}\right)$

$= \sigma^2\Bigl( \mathbf {u'\left(X_1'X_1\right)^{-1}X_1'\left(I - S\right)'\left(I - S\right)X_1\left(X_1'X_1\right)^{-1}u - u'\left(X_1'X_1\right)^{-1}X_1'X_1\left(X_1'X_1\right)^{-1}u}\Bigr)$

$= \sigma^2\Bigl(\mathbf {z'(I - S)'(I - S)z - z'z}\Bigr)$

$\Bigl($Where $\mathbf z = \mathbf {X_1\left(X_1'X_1\right)^{-1}u}$   $\Bigr)$

$= \sigma^2\Bigl(\mathbf {z'SS'z - z'S'z -z'Sz}\Bigr)$

Now this is where I am stuck. I know that the first term in the brackets is non-negative as the matrix $\mathbf {SS'}$ is non-negative definite, but the two negative terms are something that I am completely unable to comment on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to simultaneously cross-post the same question on two (or more?) different forums, please list the other forums and keep each forum informed as to the status (especially if you've accepted an answer).  Otherwise you're wasting folks' time.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377500/higher-variance-due-to-overfitting

Comment: Sure, I'll gladly keep the forum(s) informed if someone graces my question with an answer. Until then, what else can I do?